# remove blank space after single quotes in a string (using awk or sed)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Below is the input file:

```
select a, b,c, a1 as ' value1 ', a2 as ' value2 ', d from table1;
```

Given file can have any number of aliases. I want to remove space between the quotes.
The desired output is:

```
select a,b,c, a1 as 'value1', a2 as 'value2',d from table1;
```

Will it be possible using awk or sed?

Comment: Your examples and your description don't match. Your desired output has more spaces removed than just those in quotes.

Comment: @user161778: i am considering quoted string only...ignore other spaces..when i am running the first script i am getting error...and when i remove the space between quotes...the query is running perfectly fine..dont know the exact reason

Comment: Have you tried anything for this yet? If so show what you've tried. If not, do that first.

Answer (score 2):

With gawk you can use `gensub`:

```
$ cat q.txt
select a, b,c, a1 as ' value1 ', a2 as ' value2 ', d from table1;

$ cat q.awk
{ print gensub(/' *([^' ]+) *'/, "'\\1'", "g") }

$ gawk -f q.awk q.txt
select a, b,c, a1 as 'value1', a2 as 'value2', d from table1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -r "s/' +([^']*) +'/'\1'/g" file
select a, b,c, a1 as 'value1', a2 as 'value2', d from table1;
```

Comment: If there are multiple spaces following the value before the trailing quote (e.g., `' value........'`, where the dots are spaces) the subexpression will include all but the last space.

Comment: Yes that's true so the trailing `+` is redundant. The obvious way to try to avoid that would be to include a space in the bracket expression but then it'd fail if `value[N]` could contain spaces. We'll have to wait for the OP to tell us if their input doesn't exactly match what they posted what it really looks like.

Comment: Excellent point. I agree --- it's up to OP to put the variety of possible input cases that need to be addressed (which he or she may well have already done).

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time using sed because basic and extended Posix/GNU both don't recognize the non-greedy quantifier `?`.  Anyway, if you can use perl, here's one way to do it:

```
perl -pe "s/'\s*(.*?)\s*'/'\1'/g" input_file.txt
```

Edit:

Ah yes, I like the solution @edmorton gave.  You can use `[^'*]` instead of the greedy quantifier `?`.  So to use sed you can do:

```
sed -r "s/'\s+([^']*)\s+'/'\1'/g" input_file.txt
```